# Euclidean projection of a bounded sequence is a bounded sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization

Let $(x_k)$ be a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $y_k=\arg \min_{z \in C}\|z-x_k\|$ where $C$ is a closed convex set. Show $(y_k)$ is a bounded sequence.

**My try**

For each $k$ we can write $\|y_k\|\leq \|y_k-x_k\|+\|x_k\|$. Then we need to show $\|y_k-x_k\|$ is bounded for all $k$. Define $e_k:=\|y_k-x_k\|$. We need to show $(e_k)$ is bounded. Suppose to the contrary that $(e_k)$ is not bounded. Then for all $M>0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $e_k>M$ for all $k \geq N$. I am not clear after this point.

Intuitively, the thing I explained cannot happen because $e_k$'s are coming from minimization and this says the minimum value goes to infinity after certain steps and if it happens there is no minimization. I cannot argue this rigorously.

Comment: I corrected that $y_k$ is not the $\min$ but rather the argument achieving the $\min$.

Comment: Since $y_k$ is the closest point to $x_k$ in $C$ it cannot be further from $x_k$ than $y_1$, so $\|y_k-x_k\|\leq\|y_1-x_k\|\leq\|y_1\|+\|x_k\|$, and the right hand side is bounded by assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Fix any arbitrary $z_0 \in C$. By assumption $\exists M > 0 \;|\; \forall x_k \in C, \|x_k\| \leq M.$ Then pick $y_k \in C$. Note that
$$\|y_k - x_k\| = \min_{z \in C}\|z - x_k\| \leq \|z_0 - x_k\| \leq \|z_0\| + \|x_k\| \leq \|z_0\| + M.$$
Now use the triangle inequality to show
$$\|y_k\| \leq \|z_0\| + 2M.$$

Comment: Your proof is for a fixed $y_k$. We are not fixing a $y_k$ and we want a result that holds for all $y_k$'s. Please follow my proof because as I explained your proof does not show for all $y_k$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, I've shown for any $y_k$, $\|y_k\| \leq \|z_0\|+ 2M$ where $z_0$ is any point in $C$. The constant on the right doesn't depend on $y_k$ or $x_k$.

Comment: Your proof shows each individual element of the sequence is bounded, how can you say the entire sequence $(y_k)$ is bounded?

Comment: The bound is uniform, it doesn't depend on $y_k$. $z_0$ and $M$ are independent of $y_k$.